# biblatex: Modify cite numbers just in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, citing

Is it possible to change just the **citation number** in the **bibliography** to **sans-serif**? I tested already the following code, but nothing changed. I think there is a simple hook for this?!

```
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{[\textsf{#1}]}
\makeatother
```

**Explaining example:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[style=ieee,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\cite{Test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Bib.bib:**

```
@article{Test,
author      ={Test, A.},
title       ={Human cells},
journal     ={Biology},
year        ={2018},
}
```

Comment: `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\textsf{#1}}` to change it everywhere and `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{\textsf{#1}}}` to change it only in the bibliography.

Comment: Solved with the comment from @moewe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\textsf{#1}}
```

changes the citation number in all contexts to sans serif

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{\textsf{#1}}}
```

only changes the label in the bibliography

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{\textsf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{sigfridsson} ipsum \cite{worman} dolor \cite{geer} sit \cite{vizedom:related} amet.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The effect is not very pronounced for the 1 but clearly visible for 2, 3 and 4.